# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence directly causes snother error TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I have a matrix that contains *n* arrays. Each array represent some values associated to a simple picture.
I want to cluster with KMeans the arrays in the Matrix, but when I fit the model I got the error:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

This is my code. What should I change?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
from matplotlib import style 
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans 
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
from pymongo import MongoClient
import numpy

model = KMeans(n_clusters=4, random_state=0)

client = MongoClient()
db = client['competitors']
coll = db['competitors_posts_score']

points = []

for u in coll.find():
    for p in u['posts_score']:
        if len(p)==0:
            continue
        points.append(numpy.asarray(p))

X = numpy.asarray([points])

model.fit(X)
```